# How to ignore some entity attributes changes on dirty check with JPA Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am using JPA 2.1 and Hibernate 5.1 in my project, I have a module in which I am creating my entities only with JPA annotations. I can't make it depend on hibernate annotations

In this module, I have an entity with this attributes declaration :

```
@javax.persistence.Column(name = "lastModified", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
@Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
private java.util.Date lastModified = null;

@javax.persistence.Column(name = "version", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@Version
private Long version = null;
```

This way, when Hibernate is persisting or loading my entity, the type of `lastModified` is changed to `java.sql.Timestamp`.

The problem is:
When I create a new instance of my entity, I set an id value that exists on database, I call `entitymanager.merge(entity)` so that entity will be loaded and becomes managed. I am not doing any change on my entity but Hibernate dirty check is detecting the attribute lastModified is null and it is making an update query for that and finally the field version is incremented.
Also, if I set the value of the attribute `lastModified` with a Date (equal to the value in database), the dirty-check is detecting a change on this field and makes an update query, because it it compares it to the `loadedState` which is a Timestamp

What I want is to make Hibernate dirty-check ignore this field lastModified, I found the annotation `@OptimisticLock(excluded = true)` but this is Hibernate annotation, I cannot use it in my module for other constraints

Have you any suggestion please?

Comment: After merge, what are you possibly doing with the Entity? Not saving changes? Why it needs to be managed if you do not modify, persist & increase version?

Comment: of course I have to save it after merge, but when I receive a json containing no modifications to the state in datastore, why an update request is generated and the version field is incremented ? that's my issue and that's why I am trying to ignore that lastModified attribute in hibernate dirty check

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is : When I create a new instance of my entity, I set an id value that exists on database, I call entitymanager.merge(entity) so that entity will be loaded and becomes managed.

Any reason why you are not simply loading the entity
using `EntityManager#find`? Similar to

```
final int id = 42; // coming from a request or else, assuming your ID is of type int of course
final PersistentObject po = entityManager.find(PersistentObject.class, id);
// Further use of po
```

Comment: because it is a rest webservice and I have a specific parser that is parsing json data and creating a new instance of entity using reflection

Comment: Sure, if you want to re-invent the wheel and rather spend time working around JPA go ahead, then my solution won't be of help :-)

Comment: That's not what I want, I am just facing lot of constraints in this project and I am searching for the best alternative. thanks anyway :-)